# Two libraries which can expand each other

Tags: c++, class, lib

So I'm working on an Modular C++ library for me and my team. Here is my situation:

I have a library `A` which contains a complex storage control `class a`. I have also a library `B` that is something like a interface to an complex protocol which contains an special response. Now, I want to have a function in class a, which CAN use `B`. This can be helpful for Program `X`, which uses `A` and `B`. But there is also Program `Y`, which will only use `A` and not the complex library `B`.

How can I get this behavior in C++? Do I need macros, symbols or is there an other way to implement this easily so that I don't need to include an extra file in a Program? Which type of library is the better one?

Comment: I strongly urge you to rethink your approach. This sounds like it may be better addressed through proper use of inheritance.

Comment: huh? you want to use the libray B without using library B? I am confused...

Comment: @bolov eehh... i don't understand what you mean... i want t to have functions aviable only when two librarys are "available"

Comment: I second the person saying to rethink your approach, but barring that you could use something like preprocessor conditions. `#ifdef USING_A` followed by the lines that use A, then `#else` followed by the lines the use B, followed by `#endif`. You can have one library that is compiled differently based on what flags you compile your project with, but this will probably mean code duplication and a general increase in complexity. If the difference in functionality is simple & isolated this might suffice.

Comment: @Thebluefish ok... but how can do this "better"... is there a special preprocessor syntax?

Comment: See [Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Drise I try to improve myself... I apologize for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty common in system libraries, where optional features can be chosen at (library) compile time. With this approach, you would have one or more `#define` preprocessor macros guarding the optional features. Thus, in library A:

```
#ifdef USE_LIBRARY_B
#include <b/foo.h>
int A_optional_feature_using_B(void) { ... }
#endif

// rest of library A follows
```

At compile time you would either define `USE_LIBRARY_B` or not (and add any necessary linker flags of course). For example, with `gcc` on a UNIX-like platform:

```
$ gcc ... -DUSE_LIBRARY_B ...
```

Most commonly, something like [`autoconf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) is used for UNIX environments to give the end-user an easy way to select the optional features. Thus, you might see:

```
me@pc:library_a$ ./configure --with-library-b
```

See the `autoconf` documentation for information on how to set something like that up.

On Windows, you could do something similar (e.g., in Visual Studio, use different Project/Solution configurations that define the appropriate macros).

---

The above gives you *compile-time only* control over the extra features. To allow the choice to be made at *runtime* so that the library can use B if present, you will need to use runtime dynamic linking. This is highly platform-specific. On Linux, use [`libdl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). On Windows, use [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and friends. Here you will have to do a lot of extra coding to look for and load the optional library if present and to return appropriate error codes / exceptions if not present and functions requiring the optional library are called.

---

If all this sounds like a pain in the rear, you're right, it is. If there is any reasonable way to adjust your strategy so that you don't have to do this, you will be better off. But for some use cases this *is* necessary and appropriate and if yours is so, then I hope the above gives you some starting points, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks... i think, i can work with this... so i think, i must find a way around. Because, when i have 6 librarys wich can use eachother, this will be the hell, for me, and for my team.